# @DynamoDBAttribute annotation not working

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table named opx_user_profiles. The entity is shown below, however the attribute user_profile_id is getting saved as userProfileID in the table, even though the  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = USER_PROFILE_ID) is specified on the attribute. Other attributes like date_created are getting saved as expected.
I have read the documentation but still not able to find the root cause of the issue. Is it is a bug in dynamo DB?

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "opx_user_profiles")
    public class UserProfileEntity implements Serializable
    {

        public static final String USER_PROFILE_ID="user_profile_id";
        public static final String DATE_CREATED = "date_created";
        public static final String EXPIRY_DATE = "expiry_date";
        public static final String USERNAME ="username";
        public static final String CONTACT_NAME ="contact_name";


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = USER_PROFILE_ID)
        private Integer userProfileId;

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = USERNAME)
        private String userName;

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = CONTACT_NAME)
        private String contactName;

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = DATE_CREATED)
        private Date dateCreated;


        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = EXPIRY_DATE)
        private long expiryDate;

        public Integer getUserProfileID()
        {
            return userProfileId;
        }

        public void setUserProfileID(Integer userProfileId)
        {
            this.userProfileId = userProfileId;
        }

        public String getUserName()
        {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName)
        {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getContactName()
        {
            return contactName;
        }

        public void setContactName(String contactName)
        {
            this.contactName = contactName;
        }

        public Date getDateCreated()
        {
            return dateCreated;
        }

        public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated)
        {
            this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was likely due to the mismatch between the getter and field name; the getter & setter use "ID" and the field is "Id" so the annotation couldn't find the getter & setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the official AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAttribute.html) says we may apply the annotation @DynamoDBAttribute class field, I could not make it work like this. However, as seen in this AWS [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBAttribute), I could apply without any problem the annotation to the getter methods.

Please try the following:

```
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "opx_user_profiles")
    public class UserProfileEntity implements Serializable
    {

        public static final String USER_PROFILE_ID="user_profile_id";
        ...
        private Integer userProfileId;
        ...    
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = USER_PROFILE_ID)
        public Integer getUserProfileID()
        {
            return userProfileId;
        }

        public void setUserProfileID(Integer userProfileId)
        {
            this.userProfileId = userProfileId;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot to update the question, but this is what I tried and it worked. Thanks!.

Comment: An important note is that if you put the annotation on the field, you need to define getters and setters: "If the annotation is applied directly to the class field, the corresponding getter and setter must be declared in the same class." So the field annotation is only really useful if you're using something that auto-generates getters/setters (like Lombok)

Answer (score 1):

One more option.
If you want to reduce code boilerplates you might use Lombok's [@Getter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) this way:

```
  @Getter(onMethod = @__({@DynamoDbAttribute("address")}))
  private String address;
```

p.s.: It won't impact performance cause the code generation happens not in runtime but the entity looks better IMO.