# DynamoDB/Jackson removing 'is' prefix from property name of the entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

Not sure if this issue is related to DynamoDB, Jackson, or something else.

The prefix `is` is being removed from the field `isPrimary` while writing, saving with the name `primary` instead in DynamoDB.

Not able to get the record based on this field because:

1. There's no column/field in dynamo DB as `isPrimary`
2. When trying to query with the field name `primary`, `DynamoDbMapper` throws an exception saying primary is a reserved keyword and can not be used in the query.

Tryied using `@JsonProperty(value = "isPrimary")` and `@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isPrimary")` individually and both together, non of these work.

Using `DynamoDBMapper`

Entity Class

```java
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my-data-table")
public class MyData {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "otherId")
    private String otherId;

    private String name;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isPrimary")
    @JsonProperty(value = "isPrimary")
    private boolean isPrimary;
    
    @DynamoDBVersionAttribute
    private Long version;
}
```

Read operation based on `id` and `isPrimary=true`

```java
public Optional<MyData> findPrimaryData(String id) {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> entityAttributeMap = new HashMap<>();
    entityAttributeMap.put(":id", new AttributeValue().withS(id));
    entityAttributeMap.put(":isPrimary", new AttributeValue().withBOOL(true));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyData> queryExpressionExp = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyData>()
        .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :id")
        .withFilterExpression("isPrimary = :isPrimary")
        .withExpressionAttributeValues(entityAttributeMap)
        .withLimit(1);

    List<MyData> list = dynamoDBMapper.query(MyData.class, queryExpressionExp);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(list.get(0));
}
```

Write operation to make `isPrimary=true` for given `id` and `otherId` rest `false`

```java
public void activate(String id, String otherId) {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> entityAttributeMap = new HashMap<>();
    entityAttributeMap.put(":id", new AttributeValue().withS(id));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyData> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyData>()
        .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :id")
        .withExpressionAttributeValues(entityAttributeMap);

    List<MyData> list = dynamoDBMapper.query(MyData.class, queryExpression);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("MyData", "id", id);
    }
    list.stream()
        .forEach(item ->
            item.setPrimary(idPEntityItem.getOtherId().equals(otherId))
        );
    list.forEach(dynamoDBMapper::save);
}
```

Comment: can you remove @Data and add your own setter for isPrimary and see if that helps?

Comment: Boolean fields shouldn't start with `is`, only the getter should. Due to this, Lombok will skip the second "is" when it generates the getter, and in addition, the DynamoDB library probably isn't able to match your field to the getter/setter. Put the `@DynamoDBAttribute` annotation on a custom getter as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60862310/1915448